# Compare UTC NOW to a date field, T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I've a `datetime` field with value such as `2014-06-12 23:17:39.657`

I need to check if this date is greater of less then the current time in UTC.

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Name
WHERE expire_time > GETUTCDATE()
```

This is code, a part of the stored procedure, and it is not working as expected. It is returning all the records, even there are few rows where Table.expire_time > UTCNOW.

How can I retrieve all the record in the table where expire date is greater than the UTC time?

Comment: If you're working with UTC, why is the column defined as `datetime` rather than `datetimeoffset`? In general, the query looks correct, but the server's timezone might have an effect.

Comment: When assigning value to the column I'm using `DateTime.UtcNow()` in C#, and I thought I would be able to compare the field value to the time in UTC in T-SQL code, on database side. I am wrong on doing this? It MUST be `datetimeoffset`? Or I can go with current solution? Does it play a significant role?

Comment: It does not need to be a `datetimeoffset`.  SQL's `datetime` has no time zone. It's like using a `DateTime` in C# where the kind is `Unspecified`.  You can certainly store UTC values into a SQL `datetime` field and compare directly against `getutcdate()`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.  Perhaps the data is not what you think it is, or the clock is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the following selects are returning the expected value:

```
select case when (cast('2014-06-14 T11:01:50.000' as datetimeoffset) > getutcdate()) then '1' else '0'end
select case when (cast('2014-06-14' as datetime) > getutcdate()) then '1' else '0'end
```

Notice that the date there is future (at least for me now)

I would encorage you to check your enviroment variables such as your clock and its sync... and maybe `expire_time` is not what you think it is... also, further investigate by trying static values at first...